# NGINX config regex issue

Tags: regex, configuration, nginx

I'm a little bit lost here. In my nginx conf file I want a rule that states this:

```
if $request_uri does not contain following words (css|images|js) then rewrite all to /index.php
```

this is what I got, but it doesn't work:

```
if ($request_uri ~ !(images|css|js)) {
    rewrite $ /index.php;
}
```

I think the regex isn't matching up?

**Edit: this is the solution**

```
if ($request_uri !~* (images|css|js)) {
    rewrite $ /index.php;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) and expensive.
2. Use Positive Logic instead.

Better to put all static content in a directory.

```
-static 
 |--images
 |--css
 |--js


server {
  server_name www.foo.com;
  root /your_nginx_root/;

  location / {
    index  index.php;
  }

  location /static {
    add_header Cache_control "public";
    expires max;
  }

  error_page 301 302 400 401 402 403 404 405      /index.php;
  error_page 406 408 409 410 411 412 413 414      /index.php;
  error_page 415 416 495 496 497 500 501 502      /index.php;
  error_page 503 504 507                          /index.php;
}
```

**EDIT:**Try this

```
if ($request_uri !~* (images|css|js)) {
    rewrite $ /index.php;
}
```

Comment: I know, my static files are in a static folder, but eventually the regex match will have to be something like this (js|css|sitemap|images|fonts|media|uploads|pdf|callbacks)

Comment: if they are in directories better to use this approach, if not, let me check your conditional.

Comment: @Bundy made an edit please check if works, I can't test it here.

Comment: Thanks, it almost worked :)  Added the rewrite that worked (for me) in my question